# How I open Sp on sql managemet studio via VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssms

How I open Sp on sql managemet studio via VS2015?

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String")) {
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
  Int32 rowsAffected;

  cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

  sqlConnection1.Open();

  rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}}
```